# How to spend bitcoins From Account and specify Fee

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, transaction-fees, bitcoin-core-accounts, coin-selection

I am writing an application that uses bitcoin wallet accounts to specify what addresses belong to what user. I have been reading the documentation trying to find a way to spend Bitcoins specifying the **account from**, **address to**, and **miners fee**.

After reading the documentation, I think that is impossible, because there are only two ways:

- The first one is using `sendFrom`, but you can't set the fee with this command. You could use `settxfee` but that is a changing number depending on the Kb's of the tx.
- The second one is using `CreateRawTransaction` and `SendRawTransaction`, but in order to specify the inputs, there is no way to get the inputs, other than calling `listunspent`, but that returns the inputs for all wallets, and there is no way to tell that command to only return the unspent inputs for a **specific account**.

Is there really no way to send bitcoins from account specifying the fee?

Comment: Are you querying the Bitcoin core software?

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie sorry but I dont understand your question. Please post it again thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please don't use bitcoin cores accounting system anymore (especially for new projects). It has been deprecated ([and might be removed in near future](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3816)).**

A way of solving your issue would be by calling `getaddressesbyaccount` (get addresses of a specific account) and then use `listunspent` with these addresses.
Then you could create your own coin selection and use `createrawtransaction` `singrawtransaction` and `sendrawtransaction`.